# Generar números primos aleatorios en lenguaje C

Tags: c

Me preguntaba cómo podía generar dos números aleatorios primos en lenguaje C.
Lo que hice fue generar una lista de primos almacenados en el arreglo "primos", luego utilizo la lista para "generar la semilla" al usar el comando srand(), es decir:  srand((unsigned int) primos). Entonces, declaro las variables p y q, ambos enteros, para escribirlo de esta forma: p = rand(); q = rand(). Sin embargo, he tenido el error de que mi programa no lo ejecuta, es decir, se detiene el programa.

Si pueden aclararme la duda o si tienen otra idea de cómo generar dos números primos aleatorios, sería fantástico.

Gracias ;)

Comment: Amigo, no hay manera de generar numeros aleatorios primos a nivel matematico el ¿Por que? lo puedes conseguir en este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4FgqV0F_bY. Lo que si puedes hacer es guardar en una cadena de 15 por ejemplo de manera manual, en otra cadena de 15 vas a guardar numeros aleatorios del 1 al 15[Que no se repita ninguno, es decir que si se guarda el 7, este no debe volver a salir] al tener estos dos arreglos por ejemplo imprimes la cadena donde se almacena los números primos en la posición i de donde guardaste los numeros aleatorios y asi puedes manejar esa aleatoriedad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que la función srand no recibe un arreglo, sino lo que recibe en un valor entero como semilla. Muchas personas lo utilizan así

```
srand(time(NULL))
```

Pero si quieres obtener los mismos valores aleatorios en cada ejecución entonces utiliza un entero fijo como parámetro.
Luego para obtener los primos aleatorios simplemente utiliza:

```
int p = primos[rand() % PS]; //PS representa el tamaño del arreglo "primos"
int q = primos[rand() % PS];
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas dos funciones resuelven tu duda. Yo las usé para generar N primos (N = 2 en mi caso) entre 0 y 100 porque los necesitaba para el sistema RSA. Puse la función residuo residuo( int a, int b); que regresa el residuo de dividir a entre b porque el operador % hace cosas raras con números negativos; de todas formas use el algoritmo de la división para implementarlo.

```
 /*Función que verifica si n es primo o compuesto. Regresa 0 si no es primo, y regresa 1 si sí lo es.
La función utliza el siguiente teorema para comprobar la primalidad:
Si n es compuesto, entones hay un primo p menor o igual a sqrt(n) tal que p didive a n*/
long primo_raiz_test(long n)
{
    long k=2;
    while (k<=sqrt(n))
    {
        if(residuo(n,k)==0)
            return 0;
        else if (k==2)
            k=3;
        else
            k=k+2;
    }
    return 1;
}

/*Genera dos números aleatorios entre 0 y MAX*/
void generar_llaves(long x[],int N)
{
    int i;
    long p;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            p=residuo(rand(),100);
        }
        while(primo_raiz_test(p)==0);
        x[i]=p;
    }
}
```